# Emitting build file from create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, create-react-app

[create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) uses [webpack-dev-server](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server) in development mode (i.e. `react-scripts start`) to run a local server on port 3000, making compiled code available to the browser at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js.

I'd like webpack-dev-server to emit this as a real file so I can point to is from a symlink on the filesystem. Is this an easy configuration change? The config they are using is here: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.dev.js

Comment: Did you check the `build` command?

Comment: The `react-scripts build` command emits the file once and then doesn't update it when the code changes. And it also builds it in production mode. I'm interested in emitting the bundle.js file in dev mode, where it also watches for source changes.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, the solution is to just `eject` the config out of `create-react-app`.

Comment: After you ejected, what config did you change? Were you able to emit files in dev mode?